# Test multiple urls (files) with codeception and log separate results

Tags: php, automated-tests, codeception

I'm trying to create a small test suite for a homework assignment, using Codeception. My idea is to apply a single Cest test scenario to multiple URLs and get the different results, which I can then log by some identification (for example name of the file).

There are two main things I can't figure out:

1. How to run a single test with different URL and log failed assertions/passed assertions for every test?
2. How to check every assertion, even if some of them fail?

Answer (score 11):

**First part:**

I assume you are using Codeception with Selenium.

You can configure this in `acceptance.suite.yml`:

```
class_name: AcceptanceTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - WebDriver
        - AcceptanceHelper
    config:
        WebDriver:
            url: 'http://localhost.dev:8000/'
            browser: 'firefox' 
env:
    url1:
        modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    url: 'http://url-1.dev/'
                    browser: 'chrome'
    url2:
        modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    url: 'http://url-2.dev/'
                    browser: 'chrome'
    url3:
        modules:
            config:
                WebDriver:
                    url: 'http://url-3.dev/'
                    browser: 'chrome'
```

Then invoke the tests like this:

`$ php codecept.phar run acceptance --env url1 --env url2 --env url3`

For more details: http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Environments

**Second part:**

If an assertion fails, testing still continues with the subsequent environments. You can also use conditional assertions (those that start with `canSee` and `cantSee`), which will allow the test to continue even if the assertion fails.

For more details: http://codeception.com/docs/03-AcceptanceTests#Conditional-Assertions